# synchronize two pipelines in gstreamer

Tags: python, gstreamer

I am playing 2 videos in two different pipelines of gstreamer. I would like to synchronize both the videos. do any of you have any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by synchronization, what are your sources and what is your pipeline. If both are getting data from different sources unless the sources were synchronized in some form there is no real sense to what you mean by synchronize the two pipelines

If all you want is that they are in lock step with each other irrespective of what their source offsets were, as long as you have a clock based pipeline they will remain so. [say you are capturing from two usb cameras]. As long as the system is fast enough to run the 2 pipelines in real time they will remain in real time.

If you just want to display the two side by side irrespective of the initial offsets between them use videomixer and place them side by side. It will automatically ensure the two are synchronized in the sense that the videos will move in lock step with each other

If you want them to be synchronized on basis of the timestamps then you have to use RTSP. Send the output from both the pipelines to a gstrtpbin and from the single gstrtpbin you can get synchronized streams. This is slightly non trivial.

Comment: I cant use a videomixer because i want to control two videos seperately, that is , if i pause one video, other video should still run. What i meant by synchronization here is 1) starting time should be same for both the videos 2) also need to check playing rate of both the videos should be same all the time. sorry for not informing these in my question

Comment: so 2nd para of yours seems to answer my question. But then how can i start playing video at the same time.In current case there is a small delay and i need to get rid of it. currently my code is like this self.pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING) ;     self.pipeline1.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING).                                  

How can i make sure playing rate of video is same all the time ? should i use threads ?

Comment: The simplest way would be to have the display part in a 3rd pipeline. This pipeline receives the 2 bitstreams, decodes and displays them. Since both the displays are part of the same pipeline they will by in sync.To be able to pause one and continue with the other my suggestion would be to use a leaky queue to drop packets. The fact that these are two independent pipelines means all of these mechanisms are really workarounds. The "proper" way of achieving this needs use of ntp and some protocol like rtsp to synchronize the streams. This is done in video communication systems.